# Allow specific characters in the middle, but not in the end or beginning

Tags: c#, regex

I want to define a 'valid' input, which is `_-.` won't be allowed in the end or in the begining of the string, only allowed in the middle.

*Acceptable characters* (location doesn't matter): `a-zA-Z0-9` and all the hebrew letters which I don't know how to allow them in a regex (maybe just hard-coding all the letters?)

*Unacceptable characters* (location doesn't matter): All symbols, except the special ones I provided before.

I don't know how to build this pattern, and if you can add tips and comments on every section so I will understand. Thanks!

This is not for homework, just for self learning.

Comment: The permitted symbols, can they be one character away from the ends? Can there be two next to each other? (Would “`A...Z`” be something you'd want valid?)

Comment: That's a great point, thanks for pointing that out: `a..b` is invalid, but `'a.b'` is valid. Using the pattern @Yorye provided, how can I apply this setting? Provided Pattern: `@"^[a-zA-Z\dא-ת][\s\w\.א-ת\-]*[a-zA-Z\dא-ת]$"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@"^[a-zA-Z\dא-ת][a-zA-Z_\-\.\dא-ת]*[a-zA-Z\dא-ת]$"
```

If you want to allow "_.-" without duplicates:

```
@"^[a-zA-Z\dא-ת]([a-zA-Z\dא-ת]+[_\.\-]?)*[a-zA-Z\dא-ת]$"
```

If you want to allow white spaces in the middle:

```
@"^[a-zA-Z\dא-ת][a-zA-Z_\-\.\d\sא-ת]*[a-zA-Z\dא-ת]$"
```

If you want white spaces + "_.-" without duplicates:

```
@"^[a-zA-Z\dא-ת]([a-zA-Z\d\sא-ת]+[_\.\-]?)*[a-zA-Z\dא-ת]$"
```

So using the Regex:

```
var isValid = Regex.IsMatch(input, @"...");
```

Also, if you plan on using the regex many times in the code, I suggest adding RegexOptions.Compiled flag, to increase speed.

```
var isValid = Regex.IsMatch(input, @"...", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Comment: I have tested your code before, wasn't working, but the new one does. In Regex '\w' defines..? And what does the '*' is used for between the last in middle sections? Thanks for your help.

Comment: \w stands for "a-zA-Z0-9_", and * means that the [] section before it can appear zero times or more.

Comment: @GuyDavid I edited it again because I forgot to allow dot in the middle. This is now final.

Comment: Your description of \w isn't entirely true and it matches a lot more than you might think. The old `[A-Za-z0-9_]` is only true when you're using the ECMAScript compatible version of regex in .NET. By default \w matches a range of characters due to the fact that it uses Unicode matching. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter

Comment: @jessehouwing Thanks for the note! Fixed.

Comment: @Yorye and if I would like to limit that allowed symbol ('_.-') to appear only once, between letters?

Comment: @Yorye You have been very helpful for me understanding Regex basis. Thank you

Comment: @GuyDavid No problem. You can find all regex signs and special chars [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet). You can add me on [facebook](http://www.facebook.com/yoryenathan) if you want, so you can ask me little questions if you're stuck or if you want to learn something new.