# How to add a symbol character in the middle of string but not in the beginning or in the end of the string in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string array of a dynamic size.

For example:

```
string[] UserName_arr = new string[usercount + 1]; 
// here usercount would be int value considering it as 4 so the array size would be 5.
```

I need to add every UserName_arr values into a single string merging with just a special character **`<`** symbol.

When I use this code `main_UserName = String.Join("<", UserName_arr);`

I get the string as `main_UserName =a1<a2<a3<` 
I don't need the **`<`** in the end of my string

I checked out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257701/allow-specific-characters-in-the-middle-but-not-in-the-end-or-beginning) but was not able to reach anywhere

Comment: String.Join works as you want. I can only imagine that there is a null or empty string at the last position. Try `String.Join("<", UserName_arr.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)))`

Comment: I get the result by the above code specified @ Vera rind

Comment: @Verarind post that as an answer. And TechBrkTru check this out as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559415/concat-all-strings-inside-a-liststring-using-linq

Comment: Why do you create the array with `[usercount + 1]`? Why one more? To me it looks that the last value will always be null and that will result in your result. Try the code of my last comment or init the array to `[usercount]`.

Comment: u mean just because I 'm adding usercount+1 I may be getting the null value right ,but even with the code that you specified do give me the result..@Verarind

Comment: Yes. Why do you need usercount+1 instead of usercount?

Comment: actually I thought  for example if array size is 5 ,the last one should be null while declare hence I added it as usercount+1 ,because usercount would be 4 and +1 would be null

Comment: This is C#. You don't need a null value as last value of an array. Maybe you need a zero at the last position in a string (in C++, ...) but not in an array. Remove it if possible and you'll get the result you want with your code `String.Join("<", UserName_arr)`.

Comment: ya sure will try like that @Verarind

Comment: Don't forget to mark @ pwas as answer. Maybe @Rohit will also be okay, because there is a good explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would this be what you trying to do?

```
UserName_arr.Aggregate((x,y) => x + "<" + y);
```

You can check out more on Aggregate [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548651%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Or you can do `TrimEnd` in your code :

```
main_UserName = String.Join("<", UserName_arr);
main_UserName = main_UserName.TrimEnd('<');
```

`String.Join` example :

```
string[] dinosaurs = new string[] { "Aeolosaurus",
        "Deinonychus", "Jaxartosaurus", "Segnosaurus" };        
string joinedString = string.Join(", ", dinosaurs);
Console.WriteLine(joinedString);
```

Output :

> Aeolosaurus, Deinonychus, Jaxartosaurus, Segnosaurus

See there is no **,** in the end.

See `String.Join` [this example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-join).

**Edit :**

Based on OP's comment and Vera rind's comments the problem OP faced was the wrong declaration of String array. 
It had one element more than required, which resulted in being a `Null` element in the end of the array. 
This array when used with `String.Join` due to the null last element resulted in an unwanted "<" at the end.

Either change your array declaration to :

```
string[] UserName_arr = new string[usercount];
```

Or check for null string in the Join condition :

```
String.Join("<", UserName_arr.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) == false))
```

Comment: I don't think that Aggregate will return in an other result like String.Join.

Comment: I 'm getting the result string.join ...the way I want

Comment: @Verarind - yes, you are right. It gives the same output.

Comment: @TechBrkTru - and the real problem was?

Comment: I added a comment to the original post that points to the error. He has to check the initialization of his array. Will see what happens.

Comment: the real problem was just because of the null added in the end of the array size it was giving me a question mark in the end of my string ...main_UserName =a1<a2<a3< @Rohit

Comment: @Verarind its need be not be  "he ", it could be a "she" as well. :-)

Comment: Ups... Sorry... Mea culpa.

Answer (score 3):

Like 'Vera rind' mentioned in comment, you can just omit the empty user names in your array:

```
main_UserName = String.Join(
                         "<", 
                         UserName_arr.Where(name => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name));
```

The problem is that last element in your array is null or empty - that is way last comma is added after that there is nothing.

Comment: I think you should give credit to @Verarind or make this Community Wiki

Comment: Ahh, I didn't notice his comment. But he was first, indeed.